# How to copy in Terminal without mouse

Tags: git, shell, vim, terminal, pbcopy

I want to copy text in Terminal without using my mouse. For example to store a commit hash when doing a git log and use it for another command. Anyone has an idea how to move the cursor up and copy, maybe turning on something like a copy/visual mode or having a vim mode?

Comment: My suggestion would be to run everything in *screen*. It has a separate copy mode.

Comment: Similar to @poke's response. tmux is pretty great. Or, you could try byobu, which is a layer atop either tmux or screen.

Comment: read about the screen's copy mode: http://aperiodic.net/screen/commands:copy

Comment: There was a good answer over on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/125190/select-text-from-terminal-app-using-the-keyboard-in-os-x

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log --pretty=%H` to get only the commit hash of the commit in question, then pipe it to `pbcopy`. The full command would be:

`git log --pretty=%H | pbcopy`

the `--pretty=format` option can do a whole lot, actually look at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log and search for "pretty formats"

But in general, using a combination of utilities such as `grep` and `cut`, as well as the options in the command you are using, is probably the most portable way to go.

Comment: Personally I prefer [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) for listing commit hashes, it has nearly the same options as log but is actually designed to only return the hashes.